# Como recuperar registros que foram atualizados?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Como manter um histórico de um registro quando o mesmo sofrer *update*?

Tenho um formulário onde o mesmo realiza *update* de dados no MySQL. O que eu quero fazer é: Ao realizar o *update* de um registro, ele mantenha um histórico do anterior.

Estou utilizando o *framework* Codeigniter, tem alguma função que posso realizar esse procedimento? Até o momento conheço o `$this->db->insert_id()` que pega o último registro inserido no banco de dados.

Comment: Como você esta enviando os dados? Via Ajax? Ou por Submit?

Comment: Os dados são enviados via ajax!

Answer (score 1):

Quando tem um update, os dados são modificados então a versão anterior e perdida. A partir disso, tudo depende do que vc considera como "histórico". Pode ser a totalidade dos dados, somente parte dos dados etc... Isso vai mudar a sua estratégia. Aqui pequenas ideias:

**Opção 1:** quero memorizar tudo, e eu não tenho problema de espaço. Neste caso, ao invés de "update" o registro, vou criar um novo. Vou colocar um id para saber que os 2 registros (o antigo e o novo) são de verdade o "mesmo" e um campo "data de criação".

```
 Registro 1:
 Nome: Julia Dos Santos
 Codigo: 4587
 Data de criaçao: 10/02/2015


 Registro 2:
 Nome: Julia Dos Santos De Oliveira
 Codigo: 4587
 Data de criaçao: 13/02/2015
```

Neste caso, eu sei, por caso do código, que os 2 registros pertence na mesma pessoa. Ela simplismente muda de nome.

**Opçao 2:** vou memorizar somente uma parte das informações, e eu não tenho problema de espaço. Neste caso, vou criar uma nova tabela, somente para histórico. Por exemplo, se o nome da pessoa pode mudar, no contrario a data e a cidade de nascimento não podem mudar!

```
 Tabela principal:
 codigo,nome, data_nascimento,cidade nascimento

 Tabela histórico:
 codigo, data, nome
```

Na tabela histórico, vou colocar somente os campos que podem mudar (o os campos que eu quero memorizar)

**Opção 3:**
Se vc tem um monte de campos, o problema das soluções 1 e 2 e que eles ocupam muito espaço. Por exemplo no caso da opção 1, mesmo se vc modifica somente uma letra, vc vai criar um segundo registro. Mesmo no caso 2.
A terceira opção seria de salvar somente as diferencias.
Mas, se vc tem 10 campos, podemos imaginar que uma vez somente o conteúdo dos campos 1 e 4 vou mudar, a segunda vez somente do campo 12 etc... Uma ideia para resolver isso: criar um "string" com os dados modificadas, no mesmo ordem que os campos. Exemplo:

```
 Registro 1:
 Nome: Julia Dos Santos
 Cidade: Brasília
 Codigo: 4587

 Registro 2:
 Nome: Julia Dos Santos De Oliveira
 Cidade: Brasília
 Codigo: 4587

 Registro 3:
 Nome: Julia Dos Santos De Oliveira
 Cidade: Bela Vista
 Codigo: 4587
```

Entre o registro 1 e 2, Julia muda de nome, entre o 2 e 3 ela muda de cidade.

Etapa 1: criação do registro 1. E a crianção, então não tem histórico.

Etapa 2: Julia modifica o seu nome -> nome antigo != nome novo, mas cidade fica mesma. Vou colocar somente o nome antigo na minha "string", por exemplo com o nome do campo, tipo "Nome TAB Julia Dos Santos". Se tem vários campos com modificados,  a "string" vai ter varias "duplas "nome TAB valor" (precisa escolher o separador corretamente, mas depende dos dados de vc).
Como vou ter somente um string, eu pouso comprimir ela (usando, por exemplo gzdeflate()) e depois salvar numa tabela que vai ter somente a a data e a string.

A opção 1 e a mas fácil. Ocupa espaço, mas vc pode em uma leitura só, ler a versão anterior de um registro.
Com a opção 2, precisa bem saber os campos que vc vai salvar
A opção 3 ocupa pouco espaço. Ela e mas complicado. Também, para "reconstruir" um registro anterior, precisa ler todas as versões a partir da mas "anterior", e registro depois registro, reconstruir a valor completa.

Esperando que isso vai ajudar vc.

Comment: Certo, vou analisar as 3 opções!Agradecido!